# How to find the minimal function of this functional using Euler Method for extremals?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

The original functional was $\ J[x]= \int_{0}^{1} x \cdot f(x) \cdot f'(x) dx $ with $\ h(x) =x $. Solved for the Gateau derivative: $\ \partial J[f,h]= \int_{0}^{1} x \cdot f(x) \cdot h'(x) dx  + \int_{0}^{1} x \cdot f'(x) \cdot h(x) dx$. To use the Euler method, $\ L = x \cdot f \cdot x +  x \cdot f' \cdot x$ such that $\ L_{f} = x^2, L_{f'} = x^2, \frac{d}{dx}L_{f'}=2x $. However, I must have made a mistake that I can't see with that because it yields $\ x^2-2x =0 $ which doesn't tell me anything about what $\ f $ must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional is

$$J[f]=\int_0^1 L(x,f(x),f'(x))\,dx=\int_0^1 xf(x)f'(x)\,dx$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation for this functional, with $L=xff'$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial f}L(x,f,f')-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial f'}L(x,f,f')&=\frac{\partial }{\partial f}(xff')-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial f'}(xff')\\\\
&=xf'-\frac{d}{dx}(xf)\\\\
&=-f
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the functional has a stationary point for $f(x)\equiv 0$.

At $f=0$, $J[f]=0$, which is not necessarily an extreme value.  That is to say, there exist $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ for which $L[f_1]>0$ and $L[f_2]<0$ (e.g., $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x)=1-x$).

---

Comment: Thank you, I see I incorrectly tried applying the Euler-Lagrange equation to the Gateau rather than the original functional which it's meant for. However, I don't follow how the $\ xf' $ in $\ 0 = xf' - f  $ goes to zero?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  $xf'-(xf)'=-f=0$

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry I didn't do it sooner. I got that privilege after this post. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm pleased that you found this useful!  -Mark